# MODx give user group access to the content of a resource container but not the parent resource

Tags: modx

I have a Category "Articles" and in there is the Category "Travel". I want to allow a user group to add and edit articles as children of travel, but they should not be able to edit the page travel. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

use a different resource group for the Travel and Articles resources.

***UPDATE***
You might have to create a new policy for these users, OR probably the easiest thing to do is to customize the manager form and hide/disable the fields you don't want edited from the groups/users you don't want to have access to. [admin->security->form customization]

Comment: This is as far as I got so far, also. But when I block a Group to edit the Resource Travel, they can not add resources inside of Travel either.